# Calling UIViewController dismiss and/or present in an async context?

Tags: swift, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, swift-concurrency

According to [Calling Objective-C APIs Asynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/calling-objective-c-apis-asynchronously) methods imported from Objective-C that meet certain requirements are "imported as two methods", where one is `async` instead of having a completion block.

> If the method has more than one parameter, and the last parameter’s selector piece is one of the following, Swift imports the method as an asynchronous method
> ...
>
> - `completion`

The Objective-C signature for `UIViewController` [`present(_:animated:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) is [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller?language=objc).

So based on this `present` ought to have an async alternative that looks like:

`func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool) async`

Similarly for other methods, like `dismiss`.

But Xcode doesn't seem to have any built-in async versions of these methods.

I think these methods are still imported from Objective-C… if you open the definition for `present`, there's an option to open the "Original Source" and it's Objective-C.

Am I misunderstanding the "Calling Objective-C APIs Asynchronously" document? Or is there some other reason why Swift doesn't import these methods with async alternatives?

Comment: They're marked with `NS_SWIFT_DISABLE_ASYNC` in the header file to explicitly prevent the async versions from being generated

Comment: Ah nice catch. Please add that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They're marked with `NS_SWIFT_DISABLE_ASYNC` in the header file to explicitly prevent the async versions from being generated

Credit to Dan in the comments above

Comment: @dan if you ever add an answer I will delete this one